# How to filter records based on startswith

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am trying to filter records based on startswith from opportunity like i have sic code in lead page and i am trying to filter records startswith in opportunity.

My code would be.

```
newopplist=[Select Id,Name,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,StageName,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' ];
        listopp=new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp: newopplist){

        if(Siccodes.containskey(opp.account.SIC_Code__c)){
         system.debug('Enter First loop');
            System.debug('****'+citymap.containsKey(opp.Billing_State_Province__c));
            listopp=[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c from Opportunity where 
                    account.SIC_Code__c=:Siccodes.get(opp.account.SIC_Code__c) and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY Number_of_Units__c Desc Limit 10];
       }
```

Let me know how to handle.

Comment: First of all, you must not add a query inside a for loop. Then, your question and code are not clear to me. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Suppose i have a sic code in lead like 123 and i want to search related opportunities with sic code like 123,1234.etc and need to display in a vf.But with above query i am getting only records with 123 only and i am losing other records.@Martin Lezer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a wildcard character (`%`) at the end of a string and use `LIKE` to get a starts with result.

```
Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
for (String code : sicCodes.keySet())
    codes.add(code + '%');

List<Opportunity> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Account.SIC_Code__c LIKE :codes
];
```